# Excel - Checking identical rows for a product

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to establish if all rows are identical, excluding blank cells, for a particular product.  "Nice cake" would be true as it has 3 for Sun and Mon with 2 for the remainder of the week (excluding blank rows).  "Fish cake" would be false as Depots 1,9 & 11 are different to the other depots.

I have thought about using "exact()" but each product has a different amount of rows so unsure how to get that to work.  Any help muchly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use Microsoft365 you can use this formula in column 'Diff LT by Depot'

in german version:

```
=ZEILEN(EINDEUTIG(FILTER([Sun]:[Sat];([Product]=[@Product])*([Sun]<>""))))=1
```

in US should be:

```
=ROWS(UNIQUE(FILTER([Sun]:[Sat],([Product]=[@Product])*([Sun]<>""))))=1
```

Comment: Many thanks for the swift response.  I am using "365" but I get the "not trying to type a formula?" error box.  Do I need to explicitly say my data is a table or anything?

Comment: For this formula your data must be formated as table (STRG+T) your image looks like you did that. Maybe your fist column-name ist not [Product]? Looks like you have an _ behind PRODUCT?

Comment: You need to account for blank rows as well, e.g. `=ROWS(UNIQUE(FILTER(Table1[[Sun]:[Sat]],([PRODUCT]=[@PRODUCT])*([Sun]<>""))))=1`, though that's assuming that a blank in the 'Sun' column means a blank in the entire row.

Comment: So, I have made sure it is a table and amended the title to be "Product" but I still get the same error :( Am so sorry for not quite getting this.

Comment: @AlanTingey: Maybe you have to replace the ',' with a ';' ? I don't know what you language settings are.

Comment: @JosWoolley: Your right! Thx I'd edit the answer.

Comment: If I copy the formula from Jos Woolley comment it works.  If I copy it from the main answer I get the error.  Only difference is the "Table1" part.

Comment: @AlanTingey: Sorry, in my translation in english was a bracket '(' missing behind FILTER. I'd edit that. The formula should do it's work without the tablename, too.

Answer (score 2):

In `J2` try:

```
=ROWS(UNIQUE(FILTER(C$2:I$24,MMULT((C$2:I$24<>"")*(A$2:A$24=A2),SEQUENCE(7,,,0)))))=1
```

Comment: So close.  The oddity is that if I enter a value in "Nice Cake", "Depot 8" for "Sun" then it changes to false as expected.  If I put a value in any other day for the same it stays as true when you would expect it to be false.  Any thoughts?

Comment: This is related to my assumption in my comment below to @Chris. You have to clarify whether it's possible to have rows for which only some of the column entries are blank, as opposed to your posted dataset which contains entirely blank rows only.

Comment: @AlanTingey, see edit.

Comment: Works perfectly.  Is it possible to accept two answers?

Comment: @AlanTingey, does the other answer do exactly what you wanted? What if you have a value under 'Mon'? But no, it's not possible. What is possible however, is voting up answers that worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

you can compare line with line by

```
=EXACT(CONCAT(N1:Q1);CONCAT(N2:Q2))
```

or compare all line with first line per each product by

```
=EXACT(CONCAT($N$1:$Q$1);CONCAT(N2:Q2))
```

it could help more to add if functions in table

```
=IF([@product]=OFFSET([@product];-1;0);EXACT(CONCAT(Table1[@[sun]:[sat]]);CONCAT(OFFSET(Table1[@[sun]:[sat]];-1;0)));"")
```

Comment: Appreciate the response but not sure I follow.  There will be hundred of products.  I only want to compare the depots for each product.  Apologies if I have misunderstood your answer.